# spring rbac authentication by database

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to create role-based authorization in spring boot, and I am totally new for spring, I mostly work with PHP.

found this link :

https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

everything is great but there is no connection with the database, also tried to find out on how to create an authorization with the database

```
public class UserDetailsServiceImp implements UserDetailsService {
    
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    /*Here we are using dummy data, you need to load user data from
     database or other third party application*/
        User user = findUserbyUername(username);

        UserBuilder builder = null;
        if (user != null) {
            builder = org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.withUsername(username);
            builder.password(//new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(user.getName())
                    user.getName() );
            builder.roles("USER");
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found.");
        }

        return builder.build();
    }

    private User findUserbyUername(String username) {

        return userRepository.findByName(username);
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/demo/all", "/demo/add", "/demo/findby").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    /*@Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user =
                User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                        .username("user")
                        .password("password")
                        .roles("USER")
                        .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }*/

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImp();
    };

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    };

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService());//.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
}
```

UserRepository

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {

    User findByName(String name);

}
```

User

```
@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String email;

    private String[] roles;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

on browser receiving "Invalid username and password."

what can be wrong in here, the only thing that I am finding user from the database by name and comparing

PLEASE HELP! Anyone who knows spring

Comment: Is there any specific error, it will be helpful if you add error logs here.

Comment: @Atul added error logs

Comment: I guess it is not able to find the repository as the null pointer exception is there.

Comment: Add your userreposiroty code as well

Comment: @Atul added userreposiroty it is also was taken from mysql spring tutorial, user class show data from user table, i thought i can easily find and return user data to authorize instead of static data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your UserDetailsServiceImp class:

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i learned about Autowired and component, i didn't know that this annotation initializes private UserRepository userRepository;

Comment: by the way @Autowired is the most used annotation in Spring...